# Вывод результата запроса в DataGridView

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server

Нужно вывести в DataGridView результат запроса . Вот как это я хочу сделать, используя EntityFramework:

```
public static List<Output> OutData = new List<Output>();

 using (VirtuaLibraryEntities dbContext = new VirtuaLibraryEntities()) 
        {

          var Items = (from Item in dbContext.Items join books in dbContext.Books 
                on Item.Item_ID equals books.Book_ID
          select new { ItemName = Item.Name, BookAuthor = books.Author }).ToList();

            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                OutData.Add(Transform(item))
            }

        }
    }

    public static Output Transform(Items item)
    {
        Output OutData = new Output();
        OutData.Name = item.Name;
        OutData.Publisher = item.Publisher;
        OutData.Item_Type = item.Item_type;

        return OutData;
    }
```

Далее присваиваю контекст таблице :
 `dataGridView1.DataSource = DAL.OutData;`

Но лист DAL.OutData не сформирован, при его заполнении ибо Error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'WinFormsLibrary.Items' "

Что нужно поменять чтобы все заработало или как можно вывести результат JOIN запроса  в DataGridView по другому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел как нужно сделать. Вместо

```
select new { ItemName = Item.Name, BookAuthor = books.Author }).ToList();
```

сразу же присваиваем полям класа значения результата запроса

```
select new  Output{ Name = Item.Name, Publisher = books.Author }).ToList();
```

А потом наш анонимный тип записываем в лист, который является source нашего DataGridView

```
 OutData = Items;
```